# roswtf: unconnected subscription warning?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In particular the unconnected node subscriptions?

```
$ roswtf
Loaded plugin tf.tfwtf
No package or stack in the current directory
================================================================================
Static checks summary:

No errors or warnings
================================================================================
Beginning tests of your ROS graph. These may take a while...
analyzing graph...
... done analyzing graph
running graph rules...
... done running graph rules
running tf checks, this will take a second...
... tf checks complete

Online checks summary:

Found 1 warning(s).
Warnings are things that may be just fine, but are sometimes at fault

WARNING The following node subscriptions are unconnected:
 * /ekf_localization:
   * /set_pose
 * /joy_node:
   * /joy/set_feedback
 * /rosserial_lino:
   * /pid
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/404643/roswtf:-unconnected-subscription-warning?/) by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 628 on 2022-08-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

They basically mean there are nodes which have active subscriptions, but no one is publishing to those topics.

That could be OK -- as it could just mean you haven't started the node(s) which publish(es) to those topics -- but it could also mean you've not remapped things correctly (for instance) -- in which case those *unconnected subscriptions* would indicate a problem with your application's configuration.

There's no way to know for `roswtf` so it just gives you a `WARNING`, to at least draw your attention to it.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2022-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2022-08-05**:
I thought so, but wasn't sure as I had not noted those particular topics before. Thanks!